# Why is $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{C_r}f(z)dz=0$ where $C_r$ is the half circle $\{|z|=r,~\text{Im}(z)<0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $$f(z)=\frac{\cos (z)e^{-2iz}}{z^2+2z+2}$$

Why is $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{C_r}f(z)dz=0$ where $C_r$ is the half circle $\{|z|=r,~\text{Im}(z)<0\}$?

I was trying to estimate the modulus of $f(re^\theta)$ and I'm not even sure if $|\cos(z)|$ is bounded by $1$. Seems like it's not necessarily the case: $$|\cos(z)|=|\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}|={1\over2}|e^{ix-y}+e^{-ix+y}|\le{1\over2}(|e^{-y}|+|e^y|)$$

Here $$z=r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta$$

so $$|\cos z|\le{1\over2}(|e^{-r\sin\theta}|+|e^{r\sin\theta}|)$$

Thankfully the numerator seems stay rather constant because of the $$|e^{-iz}|=|e^{2r\sin\theta}| (\theta\in[\pi,2\pi]\implies \sin(\theta)\le0)$$

So $f(z)$ goes to zero as $r$ approaches $\infty$. Is that sufficient to say $$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{C_r}f(z)dz=0 ~?$$

For context: the exercise asks to compute $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ and we have to use the residue theorem and the border of the semi disc $|z|=r$

Comment: How certain are you that the contour integral you have is actually supposed to be equal to $0$? There is a non-zero reside at $-1-i$, so unless I'm just blind and missing something I think that the limit is $-\pi e^{-2+2i}\cos(1+i)$.

Comment: You're right about the residue, but this is not an integral over a closed path and the integral over all real numbers is equal to $2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}_{-1-i}(f)$

Comment: So how precisely are you defining this integral if not as a contour integral?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The integral is over the path $re^{i\theta}~,~\theta\in[\pi,2\pi]$

Comment: Okay, I see what I was missing; you only want the circular portion of your half circle.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't write it clearly enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the lower half plane
$$\left|e^{-2iz}\cos z\right|=\left|\frac{e^{-iz}+e^{-3iz}}2\right|\le1$$
as $|e^{-iz}|\le1$ on the lower half plane. So the integral is bounded in absolute
value by
$$\frac{\pi r}{r^2-2r-2}$$
for large enough $r$.